# error java.sql.SQLException: Column 'idPrenda' not found

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor más alto de una llave primaria desde Java, para así poder poner ese valor en una llave foránea de otra tabla intermedia, pero cuando ejecuto el programa me muestra un error en la columna que trato de obtener el valor.

> error java.sql.SQLException: Column 'idPrenda' not found.

```
String buscar = "select max(idPrenda) from prenda;";
        PreparedStatement pts = cn.prepareStatement(buscar);
        ResultSet rs = pts.executeQuery();
        
        PreparedStatement pst3 = cn.prepareStatement("insert into pertenece (idPrenda, idDepartamento) values (?,?)");
        pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idPrenda")));
        pst.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idPrenda")));
        pst3.execute();
        System.out.println("Todo correcto");
```

La base de datos es así

```sql
create table prenda(
idPrenda int not null primary key auto_increment,
marca varchar(15),
nombre varchar(30),
precio int,
existencia int,
idUsuario int,
idProveedor int,
FOREIGN KEY(idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario(idUsuario),
FOREIGN KEY(idProveedor) REFERENCES proveedor(idProveedor));

create table departamento(
idDepartamento int not null primary key auto_increment,
categoria tinyint,
tipoPrenda  varchar(8));

create table pertenece(
idPrenda int not null,
idDepartamento int not null,
FOREIGN KEY(idPrenda) REFERENCES prenda(idPrenda),
FOREIGN KEY(idDepartamento) REFERENCES departamento(idDepartamento));
```

Comment: Creo que el primer `resultSet`el de buscar no devuelve el nombre de la columna porque esta usando una función MAX, propongo primero leerlo en un tipo de datos int, para luego usarlo en el `insert` o en lugar de usar el nombre de la columna, usar  el indice del resulset que no estoy seguro si es cero (`0`) o uno (`1`),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas una función de agregación sin colocar un alias al resultado calculado este será así:

```
max(idPrenda)
```

Por lo tanto en la línea donde a través de rs tratas de obtener esa columna te marcará que no existe.

Considera probar darle un alias de está forma

```
"select max(idPrenda) as idPrenda from prenda;"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funcionó, sí sirvió tu consejo :D